# Is it possible to match string "\b" (backspace char) using regex in Ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to use regex to match a string that contains "\b", however this is proving to be fairly difficult. As an example of the problem:

`/\b/.match("\b")`

Will always return nil.

I've tried:

`/\\b/.match("\b")`, that still returns nil.

`Regexp.quote("\b")`, that just returns \b.

Comment: Use `/[\b]/.match("\b")`

Comment: If you want to match the literal one character string `\b` (the backspace character) or any other exact match of a specific substring, don't use a regular expression for this. Use `str.include?("\b")` or `str["\b"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Onigmo reference](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/doc/RE):

> `\b` as backspace is effective in character class only

So you need to use

```rb
/[\b]/.match("\b")
```

Note you can also use

```rb
/\x08/.match("\b")
/\010/.match("\b")
```

See [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/f0Klep).

Comment: It's also mentioned in the Regexp docs under [Anchors](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors): _"`\b` - Matches word boundaries when outside brackets; backspace (0x08) when inside brackets"_